# Write down the Maclaurin series for the function.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> (d) Another function is defined on the interval of convergence of the power series in (b) by the formula $\displaystyle{g(x)=\int_0^x \ln(2t+1) dt}$. Write down the Maclaurin series for the function $g$.

My answer:
$$\sum\limits_{k=2}^n x^k\frac{2(-2)^{k-2}(k-2)!}{2k!}$$

However, I don't know if this is anywhere near on the right track or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that: $$\ln(1+u) = \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}u^n}{n}.$$ Plug $u  =2t$: $$\ln(2t+1) = \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^nt^n}{n}.$$
Then integrate from $0$ to $x$: $$g(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^nx^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}.$$